# Порядковый номер элемента ListView по его координатам

Tags: android, java

Как определить порядковый номер элемента listview (item), зная его координаты (координаты экрана)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно просто на listview  повешать OnTouchListener

```
listview  .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BrowseThemesActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```